# Display Cloud Firebase data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hey Does anyone know how I can Display this variable url from my Cloud Firebase?
It would be very nice if someone could do a example that would be massive! :)

```
class EditProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditProfileState createState() => _EditProfileState();
}

class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {

  FocusNode myFocusNode1 = new FocusNode();
  FocusNode myFocusNode3 = new FocusNode();





  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _UserName ;
  String _Email ;
  String _URL;
  File _image;



  Future getImage(BuildContext context) async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
      uploadPic(context);
    });
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUserInfo() async {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("SerX")
        .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
        .get();
  }

  Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
        fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    var downUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    _URL = downUrl.toString();

    

    setState(() async {
      print('Profile Picture uploaded');
      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("SerX").doc(firebaseUser.uid).update({"url" : downUrl});
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Profile Picture Uploaded')));
    });
  }




  @override
  void dispose() {
   myFocusNode1 = FocusNode();
   myFocusNode3 = FocusNode();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    myFocusNode1.addListener(() {setState(() {

    }); });
    myFocusNode3.addListener(() {setState(() {

    }); });

    final user = Provider.of<Userf>(context);


    return  StreamBuilder<UserData>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
         UserData userData = snapshot.data;
          return Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      height: 4.0,
                    ),
                    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0)),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back ,color: Colors.blue,),onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
                },),
                title: Text('Profile', style: TextStyle(
                  color:Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              body: Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(140,45,0,0),
                            width: 130,
                            height: 130,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 3,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                                  spreadRadius: 2, blurRadius: 10,
                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                                  offset: Offset(0,10),
                                ),
                                ],
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  image: (_image != null) ? FileImage(
                                      _image)
                                      : NetworkImage(_URL.toString()),
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 0,
                            right: 150,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 35,
                              width: 35,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.blue),
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit), color: Colors.blue,iconSize:
                                17, onPressed: () async {
                                getImage(context);
                              },),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40),

                      TextFormField(
                        initialValue: userData.Username,
                        onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _UserName = val),
                        validator: (input){
                          if (input.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter a username';
                          }

                          if(input.length < 6){
                            return 'Your username needs to be at least 6 characters';
                          }else if(input.length > 12){
                            return 'Your username needs to be at most 12 characters';
                          }

                          if (!RegExp(
                              r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')
                              .hasMatch(input)) {
                            return 'a-z, A-Z, 0-9';
                          }

                        },
                        focusNode: myFocusNode1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          ),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blue,),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                          labelText: "Username",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: myFocusNode1.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.white),
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          prefixIcon: myFocusNode1.hasFocus ? Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.blue,): Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.white,),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 35),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(width: 40,),
                          RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
                            },
                            color: Colors.white,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            elevation: 2,
                            child: Text("CANCEL",
                              style:TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                                letterSpacing: 2.2,
                              ),),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 30,),
                          RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () async{
                             if(_formkey.currentState.validate()){
                               await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                                   _UserName ?? userData.Username,
                               _Email ?? userData.Email,
                                   _URL ?? userData.URL);
                               Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                               builder: (context) => LoadingUpdate()));
                             }
                            },
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            elevation: 2,
                            child: Text("SAVE" ,style:TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 27,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                              letterSpacing: 2.2,
                            ),),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
              ),
            ),
          );
        }else{
          return Center(
              child: SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),
        heightFactor: 29,
          );
        }

      }
    );
  }
}



BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration() {
  return BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.blue, //                   <--- border color
      width: 5.0,
    ),
  );
```

dnkjcnsjkndkcnsjkcnkjsndckjnsdkjcnsjkdcnkjnsdkcjnsd
skcnkjsndcknsdkjcnkjsdcnkjnsdjkcnsjkdcnjknsdc
scdhbsdjbcjhsdbcjhbsdhjcbsjhdcbhjdbsjdbcjhsbdc
scjbsdjhcsjdcbjhsdbcjhbsdc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

try {
        DocumentSnapshot document = await _firestore
            .collection('SerX')
            .doc(documentID) //replace with the document id
            .get();
        Map<String, dynamic> json = document.data() // your data 
        // for example to get the email value -> json["Email"]
      } catch (e) {
        throw Exception();
      }
```

Comment: json?? is that right also for flutter

Comment: Yeah in flutter a json is usually a type Map<String, dynamic> a json. But you can call it like you want

Comment: Ok but how can I display it for example in here:

Comment: image: (_image != null) ? FileImage(
                                      _image)
                                      : NetworkImage(_URL.toString()),

Comment: For the url like this: Map<String, dynamic> json = document.data(); print(json["url"]); And for showing the image use the widget NetworkImage(json["url"]);

Comment: ok thanks one last question where I have to put the code? I updated my post could you say where I have to put in?

Comment: I really recommend you to separate your logic from your views. Don't make api call in the build method because it will be call each time you will reload the view. You should implement a state management  in your app for better performances and for a more constructed code. You have many way to do it in Flutter, by using some patterns like BLoC, Redux or InheritedWidget. You can also use providers and notifiers. There is so many tutorials you can find to learn how to do it, and find the good solution responding to your needs. Good luck to you

Comment: OK, but could you say where I have to put the code ? :)

Comment: As I sais, you should check like Flutter state management on Google to learn "where to put your code"